# Why are Google Map drawing controls appearing twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I'm working on implementing the Google Maps Javascript API with React to display a map where the user can draw polygons. The map is working exactly as intended but, for whatever reason, the map is displaying two sets of drawing controls.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Am I missing something simple in my code?

Component Displaying the Map:

```js
import Map from './Map';

const Home = () => {
  function drawMap(map) {
    const drawingManager = new window.google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingControlOptions: {
        drawingModes: [window.google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON],
      },
    });
    drawingManager.setMap(map);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Map with Drawing Capabilities</h2>
      <Map onMount={drawMap} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Map Component

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

const Map = ({ options, onMount, className, onMountProps }) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [map, setMap] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const onLoad = () => setMap(new window.google.maps.Map(ref.current, options));
    if (!window.google) {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src =
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_REMOVED_FOR_EXAMPLE` +
        `&libraries=drawing`;
      document.head.append(script);
      script.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
      return () => script.removeEventListener('load', onLoad);
    } else onLoad();
  }, [options]);

  if (map && typeof onMount === 'function') onMount(map, onMountProps);

  return (
    <div
      style={{ height: '60vh', margin: '1em 0', boarderRadius: '0.5em' }}
      {...{ ref, className }}
    />
  );
};

export default Map;

Map.defaultProps = {
  options: {
    center: { lat: 36.174465, lng: -86.76796 },
    zoom: 11,
  },
};
```

Result

[image: Result]

Comment: I'm guessing the `useEffect` is running multiple times as `options` is probably changing from null to whatever you actually want. I'd add a console log in the `useEffect` just to prove this is true, if it is firing multiple times, it will generate multiple draw tools. This is the kind of thing you only want your component to render once, so remove the dependencies from the `useEffect` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @MarkSmall, thank you so much for the reply. I had the same thought at first. Even if I remove the dependency from useEffect it still displays two sets of drawing controls. Per your suggestion, I added some console logs to double check. Even with the options dependency included, useEffect only runs the one time.

Comment: Can you provide a working demo on codesandbox or alike?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `Home` wrapped in `React.StrictMode`, right? And since `Map` *function* component contains a call to `useState` then this is expected behavior, [here is a thread](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074) which reveals why it occurs in the first place.

In that case `Map` re-renders twice which causes drawing control to be added twice:

```
if (map && typeof onMount === 'function') onMount(map, onMountProps); //<- gets invoked twice
```

Disabling `StrictMode` (removing the wrapper `<React.StrictMode>`) will solve the problem in *development* mode, the same is true, if you build the app for production.

Comment: Thank you so much Vadim! I was looking for the answer in the wrong places. Now that I know about this, I realize I've experienced this in other apps as well. This was just the first app where the second render affected the UI. Thanks again!